# Error al momento de verificar en la web

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podria explicar dondeestoy fallando ? estoy intentando concetar mi pagina web a una base de datos local con MySQL, gracias por su atencion.

codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<?php

    $db_host="localhost";    //Direccion de la base de datos
    $db_nombrebd="prueba";   //Nombre de la BBDD
    $db_usuario="root";      //Nombre del usuario de la BBDD
    $db_contra="";           //Contrasena del usuario

    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra,$db_nombrebd);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El error no es legible a través de una imagen, por favor edita y agrega tu código y mensaje de error como texto

Comment: Hola! No está mal tu código, es un problema de compatibilidad de php con mysql 8.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto. A mi me salia ese error, y es por problemas de compatibilidad de mysql 8. Ejecutand los siguientes comandos me funciono.

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

***user*** y ***password*** deben ser los que tu quieras.